# plsql difference between two Nested Table collections

Tags: arrays, oracle, collections, plsql, nested-table

I have two PLSQL Arrays of type nested table:

```
TYPE nested_typ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(21);

nt1 nested_typ := nested_typ('abc','def','123');
nt2 nested_typ := nested_typ('123');
```

I want to have the difference of these two collections, for above Ex: 'def', 'abc'

Please suggest any simple way to do this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are simple types, so you can use PL/SQL's set comparison operators.  In your case you want to use `MULTISET EXCEPT` (works the same way as the SQL `MINUS` operator).  Given a third nested table you would code something like:

```
nt3 := nt1 multiset except nt2;
```

[Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o53plsql-083350.html).

---

> "This works fine when there are no duplicate elements in the array ...
>   Is there any other way to remove all the occurrences of '123' in the
>   nt1?"

Yes, use `multiset except distinct`.

There are lots of collection operators.  As we would expect they are covered in the PL/SQL documentation.  [Find it here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm).

Comment: This works fine when there are no duplicate elements in the array. Assume below data: nt1 nested_typ := nested_typ('abc','123','def','123');
nt2 nested_typ := nested_typ('123');, then nt3 := nt1 multiset except nt2; will result in 'abc','def','123', Is there any other way to remove all the occurrences of '123' in the nt1?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to use the minus functionality for nested tables.
In 10g there is a new feature know as MULTISET EXCEPT. If you want to store the output of minus in a variable then please follow the below steps

```
declare var1 <nested table type>
```

in begin section of the code you write the below code to get the minus output

```
var1:=var2 multiset except var3;
```

Check this out

```
Declare     
  TYPE nested_typ IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(21); 
  nt1 nested_typ := nested_typ('abc','def','123');     
  nt2 nested_typ := nested_typ('123');    
  nt3 nested_typ;    
Begin
  nt3 := nt1 multiset except nt2; 
  dbms_output.put_line(nt3(1)||' '||nt3(2));  
end;
```

Hope this helps.